# Am I able to pass a class attribute to a directive template in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got this directive in angularJS

```
productApp.directive('notification', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            type: "@",
            message: "@"
        },
        template : '<alert class="alert alert-type">message</alert>',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                element.hide();
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

So i can call it from the view like this:

```
<notification type="alert.type" message="alert.msg"></notification>
```

In the controller i got the alert object defined:

```
$scope.alert = { type : 'success', msg : 'This is a test'};
```

How am i able to pass the type dynamically? tried that and it didn't work. If i pass alert-success to the directive, it works, but i want it to be dynamic.

Am i able to pass it dynamically by doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change directive to this one:

```
productApp.directive('notification', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            type: "=",
            message: "="
        },
       template : '<alert class="alert alert-{{type}}">{{message}}</alert>',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
               // element.hide();
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

Since you have isolated scope use `=` to  bind parent scope property

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/862/)**</kbd>

Comment: You can also use `&` to create a one-way binding, since `=` is two-way. Just change `=` to `&`, and the template to contain `{{type()}}` and `{{message()}}`. This is useful if you want to prevent changes to the parent scope, or you want to be able to supply the directive with functions in addition to values.

Answer (score 0):

In your link function, you can do something like this
`attrs.type` and `attrs.msg` to retrieve the value you pass to your directive.

Comment: Yea but how do i send it to the template as part of the property alert type? i need to do the alert type to be dynamic, tried setting the template from the link and didn't work :(